# Azure function in VNET still needs Function access keys?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, vnet

Suppose I have an Azure function on Consumption plan hosted in VNET, if my function calls are restricted to the App Service Instance in the VNET, do I still need to ensure my function is only accessible with Function/Admin keys?

My view is that, if the endpoints are secured in VNET, then I do not need to implement access keys right?

Comment: Are you designing and operating with an assume breach mindset? If yes, ANY call within your VNET should be authenticated as it may come from a bad actor. If you think you run in a trusted environment you're all set, authenticate nothing, trust everything.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt we will be able to answer this question, it depends on your **workload** and **security requirements**.

One factor (network firewall) might be enough for your use case, others may want/need a second factor (authorization key).